# Where could I open a savings account within the SEPA area easiest remotely with an EU passport?

Tags: banking

I have a few euros incoming I would rather park in Europe for the time being as wiring to Canada would be a hassle and a serious waste of money, too. I am a Canadian-Hungarian dual citizen, with a valid Hungarian passport, residing in Canada. Quite obviously I won't be able to hop across to open a bank account any time soon. Where is it easiest to do this remotely? Hungary is *very* strongly not preferred!

I am aware of (and have) Transferwise checking accounts but those do not have any interest whatsoever. I am after a Festgeldkonto or similar.

Comment: It's not possible in Germany (even with a power of attorney personally signed by the person for specifically this reason) because of the money laundering laws. I doubt the laws are much different in the other EU countries. Now if you are a mega corp or just that wealthy, I'm sure the rules can be bent just enough by a good lawyer team, but as a normal citizen, it won't work.